# Get Twitter User Name after oauth Authentication

Tags: asp.net, twitter

Using oAuth i can able to sucessfully login and forward it back to my asp.net application.

how can i get the username of the authenticated person. At this point i just have an authenticated oAuth.

Answer (score 8):

The [verify_credentials API request](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/account/verify_credentials) will return information about the currently logged in user.

Also, Twitter's response to an OAuth access token request (i.e. the last part of the OAuth login procedure) responds with the user's screen name and Twitter user ID alongside the usual oauth token and secret.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code that use oauth authentication 1.0.

[Login with twitter using oauth authentication in asp.net and get access token, screen name and userid.](http://www.dotnetbull.com/2013/05/login-with-twitter-using-oauth.html)

```
    OAuthHelper oauthhelper = new OAuthHelper();
    string requestToken = oauthhelper.GetRequestToken();

     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(oauthhelper.oauth_error))
         Response.Redirect(oauthhelper.GetAuthorizeUrl(requestToken));
     else
          Response.Write(oauthhelper.oauth_error);
```

**Return Url.**

```
    if (Request.QueryString["oauth_token"] != null && Request.QueryString["oauth_verifier"]!=null)
    {
        string oauth_token = Request.QueryString["oauth_token"];
        string oauth_verifier = Request.QueryString["oauth_verifier"];

        OAuthHelper oauthhelper = new OAuthHelper();
        oauthhelper.GetUserTwAccessToken(oauth_token, oauth_verifier);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(oauthhelper.oauth_error))
        {
            Session["twtoken"] = oauthhelper.oauth_access_token;
            Session["twsecret"] = oauthhelper.oauth_access_token_secret;
            Session["twuserid"] = oauthhelper.user_id;
            Session["twname"] = oauthhelper.screen_name;


            Response.Write("<b>AccessToken=</b>" + oauthhelper.oauth_access_token);
            Response.Write("<br /><b>Access Secret=</b>" + oauthhelper.oauth_access_token_secret);
            Response.Write("<br /><b>Screen Name=</b>" + oauthhelper.screen_name);
            Response.Write("<br /><b>Twitter User ID=</b>" + oauthhelper.user_id);
        }
        else
            Response.Write(oauthhelper.oauth_error);
    }
```

Get **oAuthHelper** and **oAuthUttility**  **Classes** and understand how it works 
*[Login with twitter using oauth authentication in asp.net and get access token, screen name and userid.](http://www.dotnetbull.com/2013/05/login-with-twitter-using-oauth.html)*

Comment: Fine. o we get only these details UserID and ScreenName only from twitter. How can we get other detials cush as phone number, image etc..

Answer (score 1):

Using Twitterizer library, here is a code snippet.

```
OAuthTokenResponse reqToken = OAuthUtility.GetAccessToken(ConsumerKey, ConsumerSecret, requestToken);

long UserID = reqToken.UserId;

string ScreenName = reqToken.ScreenName;
```

I've posted a sample code on my blog. http://www.fairnet.com/post/2010/09/05/Twitter-authentication-using-OAuth.aspx

Comment: Do we get only these details UserID and ScreenName only from twitter ?
Also your blog is not getting. Getting error that the resource is not found.