# Is it possible to see what twitter user clicked a link?

Tags: javascript, api, twitter, twitter-feed

What if it it was a URL shortener that can track destination site profile? Can this be done without authentication?

Answer (score 2):

No, without authentication, you could get their IP, and correlate multiple hits via browser cookies.  However, there *should* be no way to correlate either to the Twitter user, absent another Twitter security flaw.

EDIT If the shortener requires them to authenticate with Twitter before following the link (which would be annoying), it's easy.  See 
[Get Twitter User Name after oauth Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1330831/get-twitter-user-name-after-oauth-authentication).

Comment: I think this is by far the most relevant bookmarklet to do the job: http://erkie.github.com/ (ok not really, but it's fun!)

Comment: Interesting, so you would be able to see which individual twitter user successfully clicked through. How? For instance, not to be stalkery or anything ;) I clicked on your twitter link: http://twitter.com/#!/Nick_Craver/status/26400446912. How can you see that I specifically clicked on it?

Comment: Haha Nick, ok thanks but that has nothing to do with the question. :P

Comment: OK, how about with authentication + URL shortener tweet?

Comment: @jprim - It wouldn't, cookies are per-domain for the same security reasons, to prevent the kind of tracking you're attempting to do...

Comment: OK, cookies aside it would be possible if the user authenticates on the site and tweets?